# How do I convert an array of bytes to string with Delphi?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I am developing a project with Delphi and I want to convert the byte array to string type. How can I do?

Example C# codes:

```cs
private void ListenerOnDataTransmit(DataTransmitEventArgs e)
{
    transmittedMsg = BitConverter.ToString(e.TransmittedBytes, 0, e.TransmittedBytes.Length);
    try { Invoke(new EventHandler(UpdateTransmittedMessagesListView)); }
    catch { }
}
```

Comment: You forgot to tell us what you mean by "converting byte array to string". There are several different interpretations, all reasonable: (1) treat the byte array as ASCII and obtain the text it encodes; (2) treat the byte array as UTF8 and obtain the text it encodes; (3) obtain a raw hexadecimal data representation of the array; (4) obtain a raw binary data representation of the array; etc. In the latter cases, do you want to group the digits?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`BitConverter.ToString()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.bitconverter.tostring?view=net-5.0) method "Converts the numeric value of each element of a specified array of bytes to its equivalent hexadecimal string representation."  You can do the same thing manually in Delphi 7 by using the `SysUtils.IntToHex()` function in a loop, eg:

```pascal
uses
  ..., SysUtils;

var
  bytes: array of byte;
  s: string;
  i: Integer;
begin
  bytes := ...;
  s := '';
  if bytes <> nil then
  begin
    s := IntToHex(bytes[0], 2);
    for i := 1 to High(bytes) do
      s := s + '-' + IntToHex(bytes[i], 2);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Perfectly valid, but (very) inefficient for long buffers due to the constant reallocation of the string.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand Yes, there are many different ways to approach this.  Above is just one example.

Comment: True. And for small buffers it is certainly good enough, so +1.

Comment: At least now we got a really good Q&A that we can use as a canonical one to close duplicates against.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thanks, i was looking for this.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect you want a function that takes an array of bytes (or a raw pointer to bytes) and returns a string containing the data in hexadecimal form.

I always use the following routine of mine to do this:

```pascal
function BytesToString(ABuf: PByte; ALen: Cardinal): string; overload;
const
  HexDigits: array[0..$F] of Char = '0123456789ABCDEF';
var
   i: Integer;
begin
   if ALen = 0 then
   begin
     Result := '';
     Exit;
   end;
   SetLength(Result, 3 * ALen - 1);
   Result[1] := HexDigits[ABuf^ shr 4];
   Result[2] := HexDigits[ABuf^ and $0F];
   for i := 1 to ALen - 1 do
   begin
     Inc(ABuf);
     Result[3*i + 0] := ' ';
     Result[3*i + 1] := HexDigits[ABuf^ shr 4];
     Result[3*i + 2] := HexDigits[ABuf^ and $0F];
   end;
end;

type
  TByteArray = array of Byte;

function BytesToString(ABytes: TByteArray): string; overload;
begin
  Result := BytesToString(PByte(ABytes), Length(ABytes));
end;
```

The first overload takes a raw pointer and a length, while the second overload takes a dynamic array of bytes.

This is a very fast implementation, since I do not use string concatenation (which requires constant heap reallocations).

---

The above code was written specifically for the old Delphi 7 compiler and RTL. A modern version would look more like this:

```pascal
function BytesToString(ABuf: PByte; ALen: Cardinal): string; overload;
const
  HexDigits: array[0..$F] of Char = '0123456789ABCDEF';
var
   i: Integer;
begin
   if ALen = 0 then
    Exit('');
   SetLength(Result, 3 * ALen - 1);
   Result[1] := HexDigits[ABuf[0] shr 4];
   Result[2] := HexDigits[ABuf[0] and $0F];
   for i := 1 to ALen - 1 do
   begin
     Result[3*i + 0] := ' ';
     Result[3*i + 1] := HexDigits[ABuf[i] shr 4];
     Result[3*i + 2] := HexDigits[ABuf[i] and $0F];
   end;
end;

function BytesToString(ABytes: TArray<Byte>): string; overload;
begin
  Result := BytesToString(PByte(ABytes), Length(ABytes));
end;
```

---

The above code groups each byte using a space character. Of course, you might not want that, but doing it without grouping is a simpler task, so I'll leave that as an exercise.

Comment: To be honest, I was really scratching my head when I saw the `3 * ALen`... That is, until I saw the space.

Comment: IIRC, `PByte`-based ptr math isn't available in Delphi 7, so I replaced it with some more old-school methods.