# Variant byte array to hex string

Tags: delphi, hex

I Think I have a big knowledge gap to jump over but don't get the Problem yet.

In my Application I use MS SQL Server to automatic create special GUIDs. The Default Value of that Column is :

```
(CONVERT([binary](16),newid()))
```

which leads to something like that

```
0x0184F4422C58EA4A95B366E2F90F5973
```

Everything works fine, but sometimes I need to write that Binary(16) into logging File. I Have a Function that generates that GUIDs for me, feel Free to use. For Sql query I use FireDAC Query. The Function looks like that:

```
function GetNewGUID: variant;
const
  cCREATENEWGUID = 'select (CONVERT([binary](16),newid())) as GUID';
var
  lquery: TFDQuery;
begin
  try
    lquery := TFDQuery.Create(nil);
    try
      lquery.Connection:=MyFDConnection;
      lquery.Open(cCREATENEWGUID);
      Result := lquery.FieldByName('GUID').AsVariant;
    finally
      lquery.Free;
    end;
  Except
    on e: Exception do
      // Some logging here
  end;
end;
```

That gives me perfectly working Variant. But when I like to display that as String I don't get it.
I tried vartostr, that gives me ????
I tried TEncoding.ANSI.GetString, that gives me some strange chars

What I get so far, my Variant is VarArray and type of Array Byte.

Comment: So basically you want to convert a binary value to its hex representation?

Comment: Yes I Think so. I would like to give that Variant to a function and would like to get the 0x0184F4422C58EA4A95B366E2F90F5973 as String

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64975833/how-do-i-convert-an-array-of-bytes-to-string-with-delphi

Comment: Why would you use a database to generate a `GUID`, instead of using `SysUtils.CreateGUID()` and `SysUtils.GUIDToString()`, or even `SysUtils.TGUIDHelper.NewGuid().ToString()`??

Comment: @RemyLebeau you where totally right. I had some troubles with that sort of GUID. I Changed my DB-Field from binary(16) to uniqeidentifier and use the TGUID class. Everything works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Olivier who Pointed me through the right Topic, "Getting VarByte in Hex notation". I found a Solution to get a Var Byte Array converted into a String. Thats the way I solved it:

First Change your Variant into TBytes. Using Code found [here](https://en.delphipraxis.net/topic/2732-need-to-convert-varbinary-to-hex-string-in-a-dll/)

```
Function VariantToBytes(Const Value: Variant): TBytes;
Var
  Size: Integer;
  pData: Pointer;
Begin
  Size := Succ(VarArrayHighBound(Value, 1) - VarArrayLowBound(Value, 1));
  SetLength(Result, Size);
  pData := VarArrayLock(Value);
  Try
    Move(pData^, Pointer(Result)^, Size);
  Finally
    VarArrayUnlock(Value);
  End;
End;
```

Than change your Binary into String by using that function:

```
function MyBinToHex(ABuf: PByte; ALen: Cardinal): string; overload;
const
  HexDigits: array[0..$F] of Char = '0123456789ABCDEF';
var
   i: Integer;
begin
   if ALen = 0 then
    Exit('');
   SetLength(Result, 2 * ALen + 2);
   Result[1] := '0';
   Result[2] := 'x';
   hublogger.Debug(ALen.ToString);
   for i := 0 to ALen do
   begin
     Result[2*i + 3] := HexDigits[ABuf[i] shr 4];
     Result[2*i + 4] := HexDigits[ABuf[i] and $0F];
   end;
end;

function MyBinToHex(ABytes: TArray<Byte>): string; overload;
begin
  Result := MyBinToHex(PByte(ABytes), Length(ABytes));
end;
```

My Final call looks like that

```
var
 NewGUID : Variant;
 GUIDStr : String;
begin
 NewGUID := getNewGUID;
 GUIDStr := MyBinToHex(VariantToBytes(newgguid))

end;
```

Comment: You do know that Delphi has a type `TGuid`? You can replace all of above codes with `AString := TGuid.NewGuid.ToString` to get a properly formatted guid string.

Comment: Caveat: an empty array results in `0x`.

Comment: Please note that this `MyBinToHex` is rather inefficient, since it builds a string by adding two chrs at a time. Better to preallocate, as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64976117/282848).

Comment: @TomBrunberg Thanks for that hint. Yes I am aware of that TGuid, but unfortunately I have to keep in as a Variant to stay compatible with the rest of my Code.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand Thx for that information. I changed my Code to fit my needs. Can you please look through the code again and say if my changes are ok? I killed my Brain to get to that Point :D

Comment: @AmigoJack Should also be fixed with the new Code

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code you need to convert a variant containing an array of byte to a string with hexadecimal representation of that array. The code avoid an unnecessary data copy:

```
function VarArrayOfByteToString(V : Variant) : String;
var
    P    : PByte;
    Size : Integer;
begin
    Result := '';
    P := VarArrayLock(V);
    if P <> nil then begin
        try
            Size := (VarArrayHighBound(V, 1) -
                     VarArrayLowBound(V, 1) + 1) *
                    TVarData(V).VArray^.ElementSize;
            while Size > 0 do begin
                Result := Result + IntToHex(P^, 2);
                Inc(P);
                Dec(Size);
            end;
        finally
            VarArrayUnlock(V);
        end;
    end;
end;
```

Example of use:

```
procedure TForm21.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
    V    : Variant;
    S    : String;
begin
    V := GetNewGUID;
    S := VarArrayOfByteToString(V);
    Memo1.Lines.Add(S);
end;
```

There is a much faster way to get a GUID! The code is:

```
function CreateGuid : String;
var
    Guid   : TGUID;
begin
    if CoCreateGuid(Guid) <> 0 then   // Uses Winapi.Activex
        Guid := GUID_NULL;
    Result := GUIDToString(Guid);
end;
```

It returns a GUID as a string in the usual format:

```
{B9DAFFD0-87E1-4DA0-957B-DFF34CA047EB}
```

Of course you may remove the dash and curly brackets:

```
S := CreateGUID;
Delete(S, 38, 1);
Delete(S, 25, 1);
Delete(S, 20, 1);
Delete(S, 15, 1);
Delete(S, 10, 1);
Delete(S, 1, 1);
```

Comment: "The code avoid an unnecessary data copy." Well, maybe, but it is still very inefficient since you build a string by adding two characters at a time (`Result := Result + IntToHex(P^, 2);`). If the resulting string has length 1000, you therefore do up to 500 copies of that string completely unnecessarily! Better to do it like in my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64976117/282848).

Comment: Hi, Thanks to your Reply but this was not the Question. I need the DBMS to create the GUID automatic. The GUID exists inside a Variant, so I need to Convert that Variant into Hex String.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand The data is a GUID, 16 bytes not 1000!

Comment: @fisi-pjm You said:"I need to Convert that Variant into Hex String". That is exactly what the code I provided is doing. Read better. You also said: "I need the DBMS to create the GUID automatic.". The DBMS is calling the exact same function as you can call from Delphi. It is only interesting to create a GUID using DBMS function if you use it inside a SQL statement without first getting it back to your application.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand I timed the execution time with your routine and with mine. Mine is much faster than yours for a GUID. The source code is there: http://wiki.overbyte.be/arch/MSSQLGUIDDemoMain.zip

Comment: @fpiette I would love to give your Code a Try. But when I typecast your Stringuid from GUIDToString into Variant, then everything in my code that uses this Variant starts crashing. Because of not much time left for that Project I leave it as it is. When I get the chance to test again I will use your Code and see where it leads me. Thank you for your Time!

Comment: @fisi-pjm You asked the GUID in a non standard format (Simple hex-digit string) so you cannot use functions using the standard format!  My function CreateGUID produce a standard format. The function you asked (VarArrayOfByteToString) don't and this is why I dodn't mentionned GUID in his name.

Comment: @fpiette: Of course it is. The benefit of using a single allocation doesn't become evident before you have thousands of bytes, so for GUIDs it really isn't needed. The point is that your `VarArrayOfByteToString` seems like a general-purpose function that can be used for general data stringification needs not necessarily related to GUIDs.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand I tested with various size. Your version start to be faster than mine when the array has more than 2200 bytes. None is definitely to be used in all cases.

Comment: @fpiette: Let's agree to disagree there. I'd say mine version is definitely OK even for small inputs. It's very unlikely the performance difference matters for small inputs at all.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it you are asking how to convert a variant (holding a 16 byte array, a GUID) to a hex string representation. If you don't mind, I also include the creation of the GUID as it blends in smoothly. I believe I have maintained compatibility with your existing code.

Three tasks:

- a) The creation of a GUID
- b) Conversion of that GUID to a Variant
- c) Conversion of the GUID to a string of hex characters

The complete process, from creating a GUID, converting it to an array of bytes (and to a variant), and to the end result of the hex string, is as follows:

```
var
  G: TGUID;
  B: TBytes;
  S: string;
  V: variant;
begin
  // task 1
  G := TGuid.NewGuid;

  // task 2
  B := G.ToByteArray;  
  V := B;  // needed only for your usage elsewhere in your code
  
  // task 3
  SetLength(S, 32);
  BinToHex(B, PWideChar(s), 16);
  S := '0x' + S;
  
end;
```

I left out error checking etc. as I wanted to focus on the core functionality. Add as you see needed.