# Delphi overloaded version of BytesToString

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.3-rio

> There is no overloaded version of "bytestostring" that can be called with these arguments

[Error documentation](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/E2250_There_is_no_overloaded_version_of_%27%25s%27_that_can_be_called_with_these_arguments_(Delphi))

What am I doing wrong?

`function BytesToString(ABytes: TByteArray): string; overload;` gives an invalid type cast while function which is expected as it's for the old Delphi 7 compiler though

`function BytesToString(ABytes: TArray<byte>): string; overload;` gives an overloaded version of bytestostring when PByteArray type is equal to `TByteArray = array[0..32767] of Byte;`

```
function BytesToString(ABuf: PByte; ALen: Cardinal): string; overload;
const
  HexDigits: array [0 .. $F] of Char = '0123456789ABCDEF';
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  if ALen = 0 then
    Exit('');
  SetLength(Result, 3 * ALen - 1);
  Result[1] := HexDigits[ABuf[0] shr 4];
  Result[2] := HexDigits[ABuf[0] and $0F];
  for i := 1 to ALen - 1 do
  begin
    Result[3 * i + 0] := ' ';
    Result[3 * i + 1] := HexDigits[ABuf[i] shr 4];
    Result[3 * i + 2] := HexDigits[ABuf[i] and $0F];
  end;
end;

function BytesToString(ABytes: TArray<byte>): string; overload;
begin
  Result := BytesToString(PByte(ABytes), Length(ABytes));
end;

function SomeCallBack(buffer: PByteArray; len: Integer): Integer;
begin
  BytesToString(buffer);
  Result := ...
end;
```

Source from [How do I convert an array of bytes to string with Delphi?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64975833/)

Comment: Your `buffer` is a `PByteArray`, which I assume is a pointer to a `TByteArray`, which in your case is a static array of bytes. Hence, `buffer` points to the first byte in the array. So you can use my `BytesToString` like this: `BytesToString(PByte(buffer), len)`. // `BytesToString(buffer)` won't work as `buffer` isn't a `TArray<Byte>`, the latter being a [dynamic array](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Structured_Types_(Delphi)#Dynamic_Arrays) (a managed reference type with reference counting).

Comment: Also note that the Delphi 7 code still works with the latest Delphi.