# Delphi convert hex to PByteArray and back

Tags: delphi-10.3-rio

How would I go about converting my `hex` string into `pByteArray` and back? using BinToHex and HexToBin RTL Functions.

My attempt is as followed.

```
function BuffertoHex(ABuf: pByte; ALen: Cardinal): string; overload;
begin
  SetLength(Result, 3 * ALen - 1);
  BintoHex(@ABuf, pchar(Result), sizeof(ABuf));
end;

function BuffertoHex(ABytes: TArray<byte>): string; overload;
begin
  Result := BuffertoHex(pByte(ABytes), Length(ABytes));
end;

function HexToBuffer(LText: String): pByteArray; overload;
var
  ABytes: TArray<byte>;
begin
  FillChar(ABytes, sizeof(ABytes), #0);
  HexToBin(pchar(LText), @ABytes, Length(ABytes));
  Result := pByteArray(ABytes);
end;
```

My function `BuffertoHex` outputs odd hex values at the beginning. Example:

```
808725DBF40100001 00 00 00 00 00 00 0D 66 6F 6F 74 70 72 69 6E 74 ....
```

Yet [How do I convert an array of bytes to string with Delphi?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64975833/how-do-i-convert-an-array-of-bytes-to-string-with-delphi) approach works just fine. Example:

```
9D D0 01 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 0D 66 6F 6F 74 ....
```

Comment: The RTL functions work fine, so if you are not getting the correct result with them, then you must not be using them properly.

Answer (score 1):

You got a few mistakes in your sources:

SizeOf is a function that return size of variable, not size of data;

You do not get any memory of your result variable, so the memory manager will think that memory of ABytes variable is not used when you leave the function and can use it for another purpose.
Here is simplified workable source of your function:

```
function HexToBuffer(const LText: String; out ALength : cardinal): pByteArray;
begin
  ALength := length(LText) div 2; //calculate length of result (div 2 coz string 'FF' is 1 byte with value 255)
  GetMem(Result, ALength);        //get memory for result variable
  HexToBin(PChar(LText), Result^, ALength); //do converting
end;
```

Using:

```
procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  xBytes: pByteArray;
  l : cardinal;
  i: Integer;
begin
  xBytes := HexToBuffer('FF8000', l);
  try
    for i := 0 to l - 1 do
       xBytes[i].ToString; //do your staff
  finally
    FreeMem(xBytes);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Thankyou @Softacom For explaining my mistakes in detail and displaying not just code but an explanation as to how it works, appreciated.